# The following problem comes when I'm going to run npm start in command prompt

Tags: reactjs, npm

npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ank.....\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-08T05_06_56_845Z-debug.log

Comment: show your `package.json` file

Comment: looks like a problem with ```package.json``` , have you installed all the necessary modules ? If not try doing ```npm install ``` in the terminal

Comment: Also consider looking into this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have a 'start' entry in the 'scripts' section of you package.json?